# Android TranslateAnimation Not working

Tags: android

I have tried and tried to figure this out, and I just can't seem to get TranslateAnimation to work properly. Instead of sliding my view across the screen, it just teleports it from point A to point B.

**Here is what I am trying to do in this example:** When a button is clicked, slide it over to the right.

**Here is what happens:** It lags for a few moments, then just teleports over instead of sliding.

Here is my code:

```
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/anchor"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="AnimateButton"
    android:id="@+id/Button"/>
```

And the respective Java code:

```
    public void AnimateButton(View view)
{
    View playButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Button);

    TranslateAnimation ButtonAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 100);
    ButtonAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    ButtonAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
    ButtonAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
    Button.startAnimation(ButtonAnimation);
}
```

I have tried this, as well as setting fillAfter to false, creating my own animation in an XML, which had the same story (teleporting instead of sliding).

Can someone please help me figure this out. And if there is a better way to slide a view, and I am doing it inefficiently please let me know. Thanks!

P.S. I have read just about every other stackoverflow post on this topic, none of them have worked so far but I'm still searching so please don't just link me to another question that's similar to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just figured it out. It doesn't work on my phone for some reason, but I tried it on a different phone and it works just fine. I'm running 4.4.4, and the other phone is 4.3 (both Samsung and Verizon, though I don't really know how much that makes a difference but I know they tweak the os a bit so I figured I throw that out there). My phone is the galaxy note 4 edge, and the one it works on is the galaxy note 3 (once again, probably doesn't make a difference but I figured I'd through that out there).

I'm going to report the issue so hopefully it can be fixed soon.